# Silverlight 4: How to add context Menu to DatagridColumnHeader?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

Can anyone give me a hint how to add ContextMenu to Data Grid Column Header in XAML?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the demo code in this open source project on Codeplex:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/

It can help you do that in just a few lines of code.